# Anaconda Will not launch on Linux Mint 20.2 Una

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, anaconda3

I am unable to launch anaconda on my Linux Mint for the last few days.

When I run the command `anaconda-navigator` I get the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/karuitha/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/karuitha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 99, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.logs import clean_logs
  File "/home/karuitha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/logs.py", line 18, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.config import (LOG_FILENAME, LOG_FOLDER,
  File "/home/karuitha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.config.main import CONF
  File "/home/karuitha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/main.py", line 87, in <module>
    raw_mode=True,
  File "/home/karuitha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/user.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.load_from_ini()
  File "/home/karuitha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/user.py", line 279, in load_from_ini
    self.read(self.filename(), encoding='utf-8')
  File "/home/karuitha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 696, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/home/karuitha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 1014, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
  File "/home/karuitha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I have tried reinstalling anaconda to no avail.

Comment: Please search for the error message to find out what it means. Apart from that, you haven't provided any information (like a [mcve]) on what you did apart from starting a tool. If you suspect the tool to cause the error, asking here is the wrong place. Rather, file a bug report upstream. Even there, you'll have to provide some more info though.

Answer (score 0):

Ananconda navigator is a gui app, you can launch it by pressing super (windows) key and then searching for it. There is command for conda package manager only not navigator.